Tensor diagram in Python
#plot
a=np.linspace(0,1,n)
fig, ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(a,(U_pred).clone().detach()[0],'g.',label='prediction')
ax.plot(a,U_test,'b.',label = "test")
ax.legend()
#ax.set_ylim([-1,1])"""

enter image description here
I drew a tensor of numbers, which should have been drawn in the form of a blue graph, but it is in the form of dots. What do you think is the problem?

The predictions look very noisy and only marginally follow a downwards trend. To me it seems like an issue with the model - does its train/val loss go down during training?

@MuhammedYunus       Yes, during training, the loss is reduced, even when testing, the error is 0.6, but the shape is problematic...

Is the 0.6 an RMSE score? It's good that it goes down because it means the net learns...but in this case 0.6 seems high because the y-scale on the plot has a similar range. It might help if you could include some code and/or data.
